What is the name of this character that looks like an upside down arrowhead?

It came to my attention that the term "caret" refers specifically to the inversely-oriented variant of this symbol, i.e., upward pointing.
Oddly enough, searching caret didn't readily reveal any information in regards to it's inverted form; the closest thing I came across was the vel, but this appears to be unrelated.
Does anyone know what the correct vernacular name is for this symbol?

I wouldn't consider this a character in any orientation. It is a symbol representing a user interface feature and has no linguistic purpose. We might find it amongst a unicode font as a symbol that can be used but it is not a letter used for languages that I know of. One unicode listing simply has it as "down arrowhead" https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2304

@mokubai But there must be some nomenclatural label that is used to reference said symbol and its states, isn't there?  Or is it purely a graphical element/icon that just happens to be ubiquitously used in this functional context?

Maybe ask on User Experience Stack Exchange?

To be honest that is heading more into the realms of UI/UX and probably depends a lot on the context of where you see it. For a list of things some call it an "expandable listview" https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/58299/why-does-android-use-up-and-down-arrows-in-expandable-list-view what you have might be an "expandable or collapsible textbox" not everything has a punchy name like a "glimbet" or a "hoxblo".

Clearly it's an upwards Pac-Man!

Drop down arrow is also a commonly used terminology.

In terms of context the usage that includes the name for this UI component would be "Click the down arrow to expand the selection".

'Chevron' is a common generic term. I often see it used both for horizontal and vertical symbols (e.g. angle brackets sometimes fall under that term as well).
Examples:

https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-80620


Regardless of direction, "caret" also specifically refers to a character positioned like an accent (at around the top of the line). If it is center-aligned (in-line), it's not really a caret.

I just realized moments ago that I've been holding a misconceived notion of what the term "caret" refers to in the context of browser/web page elements all these years.  Is there a specific name used in regards to the common web page button element that usually is a toggle (indicated by up/down glyph variants) used to hide/expose a textbox?

Can't say for sure, but I believe it's often called the "toggle" or "expander" by its function regardless of the symbol – but the specific ∧/∨-shaped symbol I only remember as "chevron". For the built-in  tag in HTML, it defaults to a triangle so Mozilla calls it "the disclosure triangle".

For me, "Chevron" is too generic, and instantly makes me think of an arrow pointing in the opposite direction, particularly the one painted on roads. For me, this is a "downwards (pointing) arrow".

@MikeB for me symbol would need both a "shaft" and a "tip/head" to be considered an "arrow".

A caret or circumflex does not have to be positioned as a diacritic or “at around the top of the line” – indeed, the origin of the word is from the proofreader’s caret (from Latin caret ‘is missing’, the sign being used to indicate that something is missing in the text), and this is always placed beneath the line, in between characters or words. The non-combining character often used for exponentiation (^) hangs somewhere above the baseline, but its exact position depends on the font – sometimes it’s at cap weight, sometimes it’s closer to being centre-aligned.

@Nicholas  I'm going by function as much as anything. However if we look at the Unicode spec, it is:  "Arrowhead, Down ⌄"   and I reckon that it would be pretty normal to abbreviate that to "down arrow"

@MikeB "down arrow" is U+2193 (8595) in Unicode. You cannot simply abbreviate official designations. Especially not if the abbreviation means something else.

+1, chevron is the name used in Fontawesome, Bootstrap, Ionicons (sorry no direct link for that one)...

(Thanks to @MikeB for the comment)
It's most likely to be "down arrowhead": https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=2304

⌄
2304
DOWN ARROWHEAD
Other Symbol
id: allowed
confuse: none

Previously I thought that it looks like it's known as "modifier letter down arrowhead" in unicode.
From https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=02C5

˅
02C5
MODIFIER LETTER DOWN ARROWHEAD
Modifier Symbol
id: allowed
confuse: none

(I don't know why they both have "confuse: none" - because I'm quite confused)

Caron ˇ
In linguistics it would be a Caron: ˇ which is mostly used as a diacritic on other letters, but standalone it's Unicode U+02C7.

I don't think it's the Caron. It's a full-height character and I think it's U+02C5 - "modifier letter down arrowhead"

Just because it looks like a Caron doesn't mean that it is, any more than a minus-sign is the same as a hyphen.

Plus, in linguistics it's called an háček. Typographers and graphical designers might call it a caron

That doesn't end in a point, it looks like a truncated version of the one in the OP so it isn't the same.

It is called a "down arrow" :)

Not really an arrow. Boomerang maybe?

Someone else already gave this answer. When looking at questions you may have an answer to, do not post an answer if it is largely the same as an existing answer.

@music2myear i agree, and if you look you'll see my answer is not the same as any other answer (you are a genius?)
